# Rank of powers of a nilpotent and the conjugate partition of its Young diagram

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, solution-verification

This question comes from Exercise 4.1 of Lectures of geometric constructions, Kamnitzer - [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0569v2).

In this exercise, we are given that $X: \mathbb{C}^N \to \mathbb{C}^N$ is a nilpotent matrix with $X^n = 0$. Associated to it is the partition $ \mu = (\mu_1, \dots, \mu_n) $ with $$\mu_i = \dim \ker (X^i) - \dim\ker(X^{i-1}).$$

To $X$ we can associate also associate the partition $\nu = (\nu_1, \dots, \nu_m)$ where each $\nu_i$ is the size of the $i$-th Jordan block of $X$, imposing an ordering so the 1st Jordan block is of largest size, and so on. The Young diagram of $\nu$ has a conjugate partition $\lambda$, where each $\lambda_i$ is the number of $j$ such that $\nu_j \geq i$ (i.e. it is the number of Jordan blocks of size greater than or equal to $i$).

The first part is to show that for every $k$, $$\mu_1 + \dots + \mu_k \leq \lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_k.$$ Following the hint (and using a linear algebra result), $$ \dim \ker X^k = \text{number of Jordan blocks of size }(\geq k) + \text{number of Jordan blocks of size } k-1,$$ and inductively this is equal to the sum $\lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_k$.

On the other hand, by construction, $$ \mu_1 + \dots + \mu_k = \dim\ker(X^k).$$ So shouldn't the inequality actually become an equality here? What part have I missed?

Comment: Have you written down some explicit examples? $\mu$ is not a partition, there is no reason why we should have $\mu_1 \geq \cdots \geq \mu_n$. I would highly encourage you to write down an interesting partition (say $(4, 2, 1)$) and find an operator $X$ with those Jordan blocks, then figure out what the sequence $\dim \ker X^k$ is in terms of that parititon.

Comment: For example with the partition you give, $(4,2,1)$, the partition $\mu$ is given by $(3,2,1,1)$, with the sequence of $rk(X^k)$ given by $(3,5,6,7)$. And, as in Ginzburg, $\mu$ is a partition of $N=7$ in this case, and $\mu_1 \geq \dots \geq \mu_n$.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I don't know what I was thinking. In Kamnitzer's notes, the partition $\mu$ is describing the partial flag variety, while the operator $X$ is meant to be describing a point in the nilpotent cone. In particular, they are _a priori_ unrelated, and the exercise is meant to show that, after fixing $\mu$, the only $X$ such that the fibre over $X$ is nonempty must satisfy a partial order relationship. What you have shown instead is that the "conjugate partition" operation is equivalent to the two labelling schemes (one by sizes of Jordan blocks, the other by dimensions of kernels).

Comment: I see - I was confused by the notation, but that seems to make sense then. If the fibre he gives is nonempty, then flags have to have the signature $\mu$ and also satisfy the condition $XF_i \subset F_{i-1}$. Considering dimensions gives the desired inequality. Thanks!

Comment: There are more nonempty fibres than just those $X$ with signature $\mu$. For example, the fibre corresponding to $X = 0$ is always nonempty.

Comment: Using Kamnitzer's notation, $Fl_\mu (\mathbb{C}^N)^X$ is the set of flags of signature $\mu$ which satisfy $XF_i \subset F_{i-1}$. I was just stating that requirement, but you're right that there are more nonempty fibres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know via the hint that $\lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_k = \dim \ker (X^k)$.

The partition $\mu$ is an arbitrary partition not related to that of $X$. In particular, it describes flags of the form $$ 0 \subset F_1 \subset F_2 \subset \dots$$ where $\mu_i = \dim F_i - \dim F_{i-1}$. In other words, $\mu$ controls the dimension jump of each subspace of the flag, and it is clear that $\dim F_k = \mu_1 + \dots + \mu_k$. Following the notation in the paper, this must be a flag inside $\text{Fl}_\mu (\mathbb{C}^N)^X$, which by definition forces $F_k \subseteq \ker (X^k)$, from which the desired inequality follows.